# How to use generated API key in GCM code android

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I want to integrate GCM in android application for which I have registered my application and enabled GCM service on google developer console also created the API key.

Where to put this API key in android code ?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use api key in android code.

You have to use this api key at server side to send notifications and use project number in android code to register device for GCM and obtain unique device id for receiving notifications.

> **STEPS TO USE GCM**
>
> - Register the Android app with GCM to receive Registration Id “RegId“
> - Share “RegId” with the server
> - Send a message from server to GCM using HTTP POST request

**You can read step by step implementation of GCM  [here](http://hmkcode.com/android-google-cloud-messaging-tutorial/).**