# How to get notifications even app was closed in android

Tags: android, service, notifications, background-process

I am developing an application that trigger notifications for every five seconds but i need to do this even when the app was closed or killed like the whats app and gmail notifications...To run the notifications i am using the service but when i was closing or killing the app notifications was not coming can any one tell me how to do this
This is what i had done
This is my activity:

```
    package com.example.servicesandroid;


    import java.util.Timer;
    import java.util.TimerTask;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.ActivityManager;
    import android.app.ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Handler;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;


    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

            Timer timer;
            Handler handler;
            TimerTask timer_task;

         public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
             handler = new Handler();
             setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
             Button buttonStartService = (Button)findViewById(R.id.startservice);
             Button buttonStopService = (Button)findViewById(R.id.stopservice);
             timer = new Timer();
             timer_task = new TimerTask() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Androidservice.class);
                      MainActivity.this.startService(intent);
                }
            };
timer.schedule(timer_task, 5,5000);
```

This is my Service:

```
package com.example.servicesandroid;


import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.IBinder;

public class Androidservice extends Service {

    final static String ACTION = "NotifyServiceAction";
    final static String STOP_SERVICE = "";
    final static int RQS_STOP_SERVICE = 1;

    NotifyServiceReceiver notifyServiceReceiver;

    private static final int MY_NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    private NotificationManager notificationManager;
    private Notification myNotification;
    private final String myBlog = "http://sample.com/";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        notifyServiceReceiver = new NotifyServiceReceiver();
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction(ACTION);
        registerReceiver(notifyServiceReceiver, intentFilter);

        // Send Notification
        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        myNotification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,
                "Notification!", System.currentTimeMillis());
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        String notificationTitle = "Notification!";
        String notificationText = "http://sample.com/";
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(myBlog));
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                getBaseContext(), 0, myIntent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        myNotification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
        myNotification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        myNotification.setLatestEventInfo(context, notificationTitle,
                notificationText, pendingIntent);
        notificationManager.notify(MY_NOTIFICATION_ID, myNotification);

        return  Service.START_STICKY;
    }



    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this.unregisterReceiver(notifyServiceReceiver);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public class NotifyServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int rqs = arg1.getIntExtra("RQS", 0);
            if (rqs == RQS_STOP_SERVICE) {
                stopSelf();


            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Try `GCM` to get notifications...I'm not sure if it runs when app is force closed.

Comment: Start repeating alarm, it will fire every time interval, you may fire notification there.

Comment: Can you provide any link for that @ELITE

Comment: read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35847761/how-to-use-generated-api-key-in-gcm-code-android/35847877#35847877)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to start the service every time you fire the timer. Instead, shift the timer logic to the Service and start the service Once only. If you need more clarifications, pls ask.

Comment: can you give me some more explination please @Ruchira Randana

Comment: You're scheduling the timer in your Activity. ie: You're starting the Service every time the timer fires right? Instead of that, move the timer to "onStartCommand" of the Service. Got it?

Comment: That means you want to write me inside service @Ruchira Randana

Comment: Can you try to relocate the "timer_task = new TimerTask() {..." code from the Activity to the Service?

Comment: But where i need to start that service in activity

Comment: As I see, you have a button to start the service. You can start the service there!

Comment: Sorry its my mistake.....Thanks dude its working like a charm.....Really awesome thanks for the answer really saved my day @Ruchira Randana

Comment: Can you tell me how to achieve this when device rebooted @Ruchira Randana

Comment: register broadcast receiver to receive reboot event and start service in that receiver..

Comment: Hi @Lakshman. That's interesting. I haven't actually done that. However, I found this article on StackOverflow which gives the answer. Hope it becomes useful!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4562734/android-starting-service-at-boot-time

Comment: Ok i'll try that and thanks for the answer @Ruchira Randana

Answer (score 0):

You're using a timer in the Main Activity for launching notifications. When you close your app, the timer stops and so does your notifications. Transfer the working of the timer inside the service itself. This will help you launch your notifications without being dependent on the Activity.

Comment: Thanks for your answer...working fine with this answer @Varun Kumar

Answer (score 0):

You are triggering the Timer Task from inside the activity right. When app is closed activity gets destroyed and so does your task.Try changing the triggering mechanism inside a service.